# Deploying ASP.NET Core Web API created with Clean Architecture to Azure App Service using VS Code is not working

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, clean-architecture

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core Web API project that I created using Clean Architecture and my Azure Student portal account. The deployment is successful however when I navigate to the API's URL endpoint it doesn't show the JSON object that I was expecting. I also checked the application event logs in Azure but found nothing.

Expected:

[image]

Actual:

[image]

The job records are stored in Azure's SQL Servers resource and when I ran the dotnet run, it lists all the records within the database. When I ran the command below it added the Release folders for each class libraries. I'm using Azure App Extension in VS Code to deploy the Web API.

Command:

`dotnet publish -c Release`

[image]

Application Event Log:

[image]

UPDATED: Added Program.cs

```
using Infrastructure;
using Application;
using Infrastructure.Persistence;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var worklogCorsPolicy = "WorklogAllowedCredentialsPolicy";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(worklogCorsPolicy,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5173") 
                .WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                    .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType, "x-custom-header",
                    HeaderNames.Authorization, "true")
                        .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddApplication();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();

app.UseHsts();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(worklogCorsPolicy);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();


using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

try
{
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<WorklogDbContext>();
    var userManager = services
            .GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
    await Seed.SeedData(context, userManager,         
            builder.Configuration);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var logger = services
            .GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration.");
}

app.Run();
```

Other Things I tried:

1. I tried creating a separate .NET Core Web API called Weather that doesn't use the clean architecture approach, after I published the application using the Release build configuration, I deployed this in Azure.

I compared this with my project that uses clean architecture and I noticed that the worklog has Release build configuration for each layer(Domain, Application, Infrastructure and API) as shown in the screenshot below: I somehow think that this is where I'm having but since there's no error thrown I couldn't verify it.

[image]

To deploy the API I'm using Azure App Service Extension as shown below:

[image]

2. Publish Profile - I found that in Visual Studio, it is possible to deploy the API thru importing the publish profile downloaded from Azure, however since I'm using VS Code I won't be able to do this.
3. I tried searching online for other ways and I found that other options are using Bicep with Azure pipeline or using Bicep with GitHub action however I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Another is learning curve since I have to learn both options to determine if this is what I need.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your `Program.cs` file.

Comment: If possible share your code repo.

Comment: Check the logs in LogStream once.

Comment: Hi @Harshitha, here is my code repo - https://github.com/ettienekorayyi/worklog-backend

Comment: Ok..will check and let you know

Comment: Even Iam getting the same error with your code repo.I feel the deployed folder structure is incorrect.I dont see any bin folder in the deployed files.Once try to deploy only the API folder.After deployment you can see the `web.config` file in the wwwroot folder.Change the `stdoutLogEnabled` value to `true` and check the logfiles folder.You can see the detailed log.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I will continue to try and find the issue.